# Region outline for USA maps

Tags: google-maps, kml, region

In USA, I'm looking for outline of the Division 9 Pacific which consists of the following states:

Alaska
California
Hawaii
Oregon
Washington

I have got a map with the KML to generate for these states: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lYAaPc-U3sv6hUlbhBsQJ0vzXfw&usp=sharing

But I just want the outline of the whole area and NOT the state borders. How can I get this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to merge them into a single polygon?

Comment: @Matt - yes without the internal state borders.

Comment: @Matt - for ex. there is a border between California and Oregon which separates them, I don't need that specific piece. Just need a full outer outline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy to try a new bit of software, I would suggest QGIS.

Load your KML, then go to `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve`

For the dissolve field, choose a field where all values are the same, and it will merge all adjacent polygons, removing the boundaries between them.

You can then save your new layer as a KML and re-upload.

Comment: I will download qgis and let you know.

Comment: Is there a software which can show me all the lat, long and let me add/remove from KML?

Comment: Yes, QGIS will do all that for you.

Comment: When I import KML to QGIS, it doesn't let me edit lat long points. How can I do that?